# JaCoCo Memory Allocation after Job is terminated

Tags: maven, jenkins, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Last week I spotted one curious moment while working with **Jenkins**. 
In my multimodule project I am using **Jacoco test coverage** and **Jacoco-plugin** in Jenkins.

I start some job in my Jenkins, when it comes to the **test phase**, Jacoco process will be created and after job execution, the process will be closed. But when the **job is stucked** in the test phase, the only way is to **terminate** the job. But in this case the Jacoco process **won't be closed**, even after the Jenkins restart. 
The only way is to kill the process.

I have one Jenkins running on my physical machine and another one in docker. The problem occurs in both cases.

Here is mine Jacoco configuration in the parent pom.xml, but I am sure that's not the point.:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Builder.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Has anybody faced the same issues or maybe has some tips or guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found the concrete solution to this problem, but I have built the small workaround. Maybe it will be usefull for somebody.

The point is to create a job that will be running one script every hour. The script is checking if there are some jacoco processes running longer than 3600 seconds and kill them.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESS_NAME=jacoco
MAX_TIME=3600

echo "Searching for  $PROCESS_NAME processes running for more than $MAX_TIME seconds"

pgrep -f $PROCESS_NAME | while read pid 
do
    running_time=$(ps -feo "etimes=" $pid | sed -e 's/ //g')
    if [ $running_time -gt $MAX_TIME ]
    then
        echo "killing the process with $pid"
        kill $pid
    fi       
done
```